# AttributeError: type object 'gui' has no attribute 'label'

Tags: python, tkinter, label, tkinter-label

I want to change a labeltext from outside of the class through a setter method in the class. Im just getting
**AttributeError: type object 'gui' has no attribute 'label'**. I tried changing the text through label['text']; label.config(text = 'X')

```py
from tkinter import *

class gui:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.label = Label(self.root, text='Y')
        self.label.pack()
        self.button = Button(self.root, text='Click', command=self.__btnClick)
        self.button.pack()

        mainloop()

    def __btnClick(self):
        changeText()
        
    def setLabelText(self):
        self.label['text']= 'X'

def changeText():
    gui.setLabelText(gui)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = gui()
```

I dont know if it helps but heres my full code
https://pastebin.com/bT43NgpH

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `setLabelText` on an instance of `gui` not on the class itself. When you call `setLabelText` in `__btnClick` you have to give the instance of `gui` as a parameter to this function. You've got the instance in the parameter `self`.

So `__btnClick` should be altered to:

```
def __btnClick(self):
    changeText(self)
```

And `changeText` should be altered to:

```
def changeText(the_window):
    the_window.setLabelText()
```

I'd like to add a link to the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Your code is hard to read for an experienced programmer (OK, not that hard, but harder than necessary) because you don't follow the naming conventions.